# addidng click event to markers in google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have integrated Google Maps in my website and i have set the markers on it

When i click on the markers i want to get the same latitude and longitude of that particular using which i have set.

For a test i have set two markers.

When i click on the markers everytime the last set marker's latitude and longitude is being shown in the console.

how do i resolve this?

```
for(var gMarker = 0; gMarker < records.length ; gMarker++){
          var gMarkerThis = records[gMarker].LatLng;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(gMarkerThis[0], gMarkerThis[1]),
            map:      map,
            title:    'Test'
          });  

          google.maps.event.addListener(gMarkerArray, 'click', function() {
             console.log(marker.position , marker.position.lat() , marker.position.lng());
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a closure ?

```
 for(var gMarker = 0; gMarker < records.length ; gMarker++){
      var gMarkerThis = records[gMarker].LatLng;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(gMarkerThis[0], gMarkerThis[1]),
          map:      map,
          title:    'Test'
      });  

      (function(Marker) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(gMarkerArray, 'click', function() {
              console.log(Marker.position , Marker.position.lat() , Marker.position.lng());
          });
       }(marker));
 }
```

I have no idea what `gMarkerArray` is, but I'll assume it's the current marker in the loop, as that is what it should be ?

Comment: Hey thats great.. You are a rockstar @adeneo. You solved my problem